# Why the same object has 2 different values depending on way of accessing?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following method:

```
unpackMessage(message : any) : BuiltMessage {
    let msg :BuiltMessage = new BuiltMessage(message['title'],message['scaffold'],{});
    let vals = JSON.parse(message['fieldValues']);
    Object.keys(vals).forEach(
      field =>{
        if(msg.scaffold.fieldTypes[field].type == "message"){
          let arr :BuiltMessage[] =[];
          vals[field].forEach(val => arr.push(this.unpackMessage(val)));
          msg.fieldValues[field] = arr;

        }
        else{
        msg.fieldValues[field] =vals[field];
          console.log(msg,msg.fieldValues[field]);
        }

      }
    )
    return msg;
}
```

It is called with the "message" parameter as JSON.parse(jsonString) where json string is

```
"{"version":1,"id":"565ac322-2eb7-423c-83fd-ce6ef09fd7e2","project":"7c5c1ad4-81c2-f8e5-504f-803605946168","title":"","scaffold":{"messageType":"TextMessage","fieldTypes":{"message":{"type":"text","args":[],"multiple":false}},"icon":"message"},"fieldValues":"{\"message\":[\"This is a test message\"]}"}"
```

Now the problem is that the output of the console log is:

[image]

How can I avoid such behavior? or how does my code trigger such behavior

Obviously the wanted behavior is that printing the whole object and only the msg.fieldValues[field] should output the same string in the underlined part in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The strange behavior is not on the JS side. Edge/Chrome console (at least) do not actually print the object as-is at the moment of console.log(). What you see in the console is a "reference" to the object. if object is modified after the console.log() and before you expand it in the console, you will se the modified version.